# How can I change the date column in my csv file using derived column transformation.The column has values in 'MM/dd/yyyy' and some in 'MM-dd-yyyy'

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I want to keep that uniform like'MM/dd/yyyy'

iifNull(toDate(toString({Hire Date}), 'MM/dd/yyyy'), toDate(toString({Hire Date}), 'MM-dd-yyyy'))
I wrote this exxpression but i got an error message like
'toDate' does not expect a parameter of type 'date'

Comment: Can you provide the sample input data and expected result for the above case?

Comment: 10/28/2019
01-07-2019
07-06-2016
06-03-2019
5/16/2016
this is the values in that column

Answer (score 0):

You can use below expression to achieve your requirement.

```
toString(iifNull(toDate(toString({HIRE DATE}), 'MM/dd/yyyy'), toDate(toString({HIRE DATE}), 'MM-dd-yyyy')),'MM/dd/yyyy')
```

**Output:**

[image]